# Relativity. Going between reference frames

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, inertial-frames

The task is from relativity Appendix in "Electricity and Magnetism" book from Purcell & Morin.

[image: The example]

Basically, I have a problem agreeing. The task is under "Question" section in the picture. To simplify a bit, there are 2 reference frames, moving with $v = 0.866c$ ($\gamma = 2$) with respect to each other. At $t = t^{'} = 0 $ origins of the two systems coincide [thats what I understand is meant by "Left edge of L ($X^{'} = 2$ feet), touched the left edge of E ($X = 1 $ feet) at $t = t^{'} = 0 $"]. $c$ assumed to be 1 foot/nanosecond.

$a)$ and $b)$ give different perspectives from non-primed and primed frames of reference.

Here is my solution:

As one can see from $a)$, origin of primed frame moved 4 feets (I will keep units for clarity). Therefore

$$  v t = X \implies t = \frac{X}{v} =\frac{4 \,\, \text{feet} }{0.866 \,\, \text{feet/nanosecond}} = 4.62 \,\, \text{nanoseconds}. $$

So far so good. Now, I assume that coordinates of this event in primed frame can be found using Lorentz transformation as (we are intrested in time only, since we found t such that $X' = 0$):

$$  t' = \gamma (t - \frac{vX}{c^2}) = 2 (4.62 - \frac{0.866 \cdot 4}{1}) \,\, \text{nanoseconds} \approx 2.31 \,\, \text{nanoseconds}.$$
Then, I assume that this $t'$ should be the time to which all the clocks in primed frame synchronized, which is not $4.04 \,\, \text{nanoseconds} $ given in the answer. Am I missing something?

**EDIT**: Maybe the more general question would be is the time we get from the Lorentz transformation for moving frame is the time to which the clocks in that frame are synchronized to or not?